# Custom Flag not appearing in "Configure Relationship: Flags"

Tags: views, flags

I am building a community site to link former co-workers.
I have used the Flags module to allow users to tag locations/teams.
I am trying to use views to now list all the users who have flagged a location/team.
When I try to add my flag to "Configure Relationship: Flags" it is not an option.
Can anyone explain this?

*EDIT* I started with a list of users, those users have flagged the node with a custom flag marking it as a work location. My intention is to connect people who tagged the location in the same way. I wish to add a block to each page with a list of those people who worked together.[image]

[image: Screen shot of the missing configuration]

Comment: What is the View configured to show (users? nodes?)  What does your flag "flag" (is it flagging a content type or something else)?

Comment: Patrick, hello.

Answer (score 0):

I was adding bookmarks for commerce products and saw this issue.

How I solved this was I created a new view and selected my custom flag:

[image]

I then went ahead to configure the view.

Using Drupal 10.2.3.